# What is the derivative of $xf(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we have a function $f(x)$ what would the value of the following expression be?
$$\frac{d}{dx}[xf(x)]$$

Comment: Do you know the product rule?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the matter? Do you know of any rules which you might be able to apply here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

What would you do if the expression was $$\frac{d}{dx}\left [g(x)f(x)\right ]$$?

Comment: Ah, so the product rule still applies here. So we can treat $x$ as a function?

Comment: @MilanTom Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

If x is a variable, x(f(x)) is the product x f(x) and the standard product rule applies.

If x is a function, you have to define what x(f(x)) means and then the chain rule applies:
(x(f(x)))' = f'(x)x'(f(x))
so you also have to define what x'(f(x)) means.

The notation x(f(x)) is certainly non-standard.